# Discord.py rewrite || Send file

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I need to attach the chat.log file to the message, but an exception appears

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vlad0\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 227, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\vlad0\Desktop\bot\bot.py", line 660, in on_message
    await channel.send('***Log for ticket #{id}***'.format(id = text),file = f )
  File "C:\Users\vlad0\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 752, in send
    raise InvalidArgument('file parameter must be File')
discord.errors.InvalidArgument: file parameter must be File
```

My code:

```
    with open(file[0]+'/chat.log','r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        await channel.send('***Log for ticket #{id}***'.format(id = text),file = f.read() )
```

The same thing happens when I read using "rb", and the same thing if you just specify the path to the file
How do I attach a file to a message?

Answer (score 3):

The argument to `file` must be a [`discord.File`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.File) object:

```
from discord import File

await channel.send('***Log for ticket #{id}***'.format(id = text), file=File(file[0]+'/chat.log'))
```